# Pivot using two aggregate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to pivot a table but I have more than one aggregate column.

Data looks like

[image]

return looks like

[image]

Sorry I couldn't figure out how to get the tables in so I have taken snippets.

I am using pivot code:

```
select *

    from(   
            select 
                col1, 
                per1,
                per2

            from    
                table a
                left join table 2 b on a.ID = b.ID 

            where 
                a.END_DTTM is null

            group by 
                a.COL3                      

            ) d

            pivot 
            (
                max(d.per1),
                max(d.per2)
                for d.col1 in (A, B, C)
                ) piv;
```

Comment: Post data and results as text, not as images.

Comment: I tried but it wouldn't work. the images do the job just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pivot twice on the same step, since doing a pivot does an implicit `GROUP BY` of the non referenced columns. You will have to apply the pivot only on a subset of columns that don't have distinct values aside from the aggregate function and the pivoted column. Try the following:

```
;WITH PrePivot1 AS
(
    SELECT
        T.col1,
        T.per1
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
),
PrePivot2 AS
(
    SELECT
        T.col1,
        T.per2
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
),
Pivot1 AS
(
    SELECT
        P.A,
        P.B,
        P.C
    FROM
        PrePivot1 AS R
        PIVOT (
            MAX(R.per1) FOR R.Col1 IN ([A], [B], [C])
        ) AS P
),
Pivot2 AS
(
    SELECT
        P.A,
        P.B,
        P.C
    FROM
        PrePivot2 AS R
        PIVOT (
            MAX(R.per2) FOR R.Col1 IN ([A], [B], [C])
        ) AS P
)
SELECT
    Concept = 'Per1',
    P1.A,
    P1.B,
    P1.C,
FROM
    Pivot1 AS P1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Concept = 'Per2',
    P2.A,
    P2.B,
    P2.C,
FROM
    Pivot2 AS P2
```

Edit:

To do further calculations, you can keep chaining CTEs. Change

```
SELECT
    Concept = 'Per1',
    P1.A,
    P1.B,
    P1.C,
FROM
    Pivot1 AS P1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Concept = 'Per2',
    P2.A,
    P2.B,
    P2.C,
FROM
    Pivot2 AS P2
```

with

```
,
UnionResults AS
(
    SELECT
        Concept = 'Per1',
        P1.A,
        P1.B,
        P1.C,
    FROM
        Pivot1 AS P1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Concept = 'Per2',
        P2.A,
        P2.B,
        P2.C,
    FROM
        Pivot2 AS P2
)
SELECT
    U.Concept,
    U.A,
    U.B.
    U.C,
    ADivision = CASE
        WHEN U.C <> 0
        THEN U.A / U.C END
FROM
    UnionResults AS U
```

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: As you are so whizzy with this stuff, I wonder if you are able to help with the next part. I need to divide the values in columns A and B with the values in column C. I have tried using a select from this code but doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BeckyPurland check my edited response. Let me know if you still struggling.

Answer (score 2):

You would also use `apply` (i.e. `cross apply`) operator to transform the data into rows from columns

```
select 
      name as pear,
      max(case when cols = 'A' then value end) [A],
      max(case when cols = 'B' then value end) [B],
      max(case when cols = 'C' then value end) [C]
from table t
cross apply (values (col1, 'per1', per1), (col1, 'per2', per2))a(cols, name, value)
group by name
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry I don't understand this. What would the value be and why are you using 'name as per'? The per1 and per2 are both counts of different things so need to stay separate. Thanks